# Wrong data when sending 1 char and 1 integer to my arduino via bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I currently doing my project using android phone to send data via bluetooth to arduino,it no problem when i was sending only 1 char when the item of spinner was chosen. However , it don't work when sending one character then one integer.
android spinner used to send data to arduino:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (btSocket != null) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        msg("In ed!");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        try {
                                btSocket.getOutputStream().write("m".toString().getBytes());
                                btSocket.getOutputStream().write(Integer.toHexString(1).getBytes());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                msg("Error1");

                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        try {
                            btSocket.getOutputStream().write("m".toString().getBytes());
                            btSocket.getOutputStream().write(Integer.toHexString(2).getBytes());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            msg("Error2");
                        }
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        try {
                            btSocket.getOutputStream().write("m".toString().getBytes());
                            btSocket.getOutputStream().write(Integer.toHexString(3).getBytes());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            msg("Error3");
                        }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // sometimes you need nothing here
        }
    });
}
```

arduino code:

```
char data;            //Variable for storing received data
int blueVal;
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);   //Sets the baud for serial data transmission                               
}
void loop()
{
   if(Serial.available() > 0)      // Send data only when you receive data:
   {
      Serial.println("Begin receiving");
      data = Serial.read();        //Read the incoming data & store into data
      blueVal = Serial.read();
      Serial.println(data);          //Print Value inside data in Serial monitor 
      Serial.println(blueVal);      

   }
}`
```

The result when spinner choose the first item of spinner:

```
Begin receiving 
 m
-1 
Begin receiving
 1
-1
```

The arduino received two time the data and with the unknown'-1' data,the result should be:

```
Begin receiving
m
1
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: `Serial.available() > 0` means "there is at least one byte in the buffer". But you trying to read two.

Comment: However , its work for reading 2 bytes from I2C communication.Why doesn't it works on bluetooth?